# How to write a custom permission class to check object-level permissions before the api-level ones?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

## TL;DR

How to write a custom permission class to check object-level permissions (`has_object_permission`) before the api-level ones (`has_permission`)?

## Definitions

Suppose we are building an online annotation tool. We have Images belonging to Projects and Users working on annotating Images. Users have a `role` field -- Guests have read-only access, Developers may change the Image fields and Owners may change both Projects and Images.

The models:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class Project(models.Model):
    pass

class User(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_GUEST, ROLE_DEVELOPER, ROLE_OWNER = range(3)
    ROLE_CHOICES = [(ROLE_GUEST, "Guest"), (ROLE_DEVELOPER, "Developer"), (ROLE_OWNER, "Owner")]
    role = models.IntegerField(default=ROLE_GUEST, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

Suppose we wish to restrict access to and within some Projects. We are adding m2m model UserProjectRole:

```
class UserProjectRole(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    project_role = ... # same as in User
```

Now we wish to set up permissions in a way that, if user requests access to API endpoints regarding some Project:

- if there is no UserProjectRole with this user and this project, permissions defaults to his global `role`
- if there is such UserProjectRole, the permissions are using his `project_role` instead of `role`

## Problem

We are implementing custom permission class:

```
# permissions.py
from rest_framework import permissions

class AtLeastDeveloper(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_staff or request.user.role >= User.ROLE_DEVELOPER

class AtLeastOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_staff or request.user.role >= User.ROLE_OWNER

class InProjectPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
         if isinstance(obj, Project):
             project = obj
         elif isinstance(obj, Image):
             project = obj.project
         else:
             raise ValueError(obj)
         upr = UserProjectRole.objects.filter(user = request.user, project = project).first()
         if upr is None:
             return False
         if isinstance(obj, Project):
             return upr.role == User.ROLE_OWNER
         return upr.role >= User.ROLE_DEVELOPER
```

```
# views.py

class ProjectGetDeleteUpdateView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, AtLeastOwner, InProjectPermissions]
     ...

class ImageGetDeleteUpdateView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, AtLeastDeveloper, InProjectPermissions]
     ...
```

The problem here is that `has_permission` is called **before** `has_object_permissions` (as it is stated in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions). Therefore, if the User's global `role` is not sufficient, he will be denied access (`IsAtLeastSomething.has_permissions` will return False and therefore `InProjectPermissions.has_object_permissions` will not be executed).

Please advise on how to write a custom permission class to check object-level permissions before the api-level ones.

Comment: you _could_ call has_object_permission manually from inside your has_permission method?

Comment: @Hafnernuss no, because has_permission don't have access to `obj`

Comment: True, but you _could_ retrieve the object yourself, as you have access to the view/request in has_permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, that's what i came up with.

I *could*, as suggested by @Hafnernuss, get access to the object in question by `view.get_object(id)` (taking `id` from `request.GET`/`POST`), but this is exactly what i wished to avoid: manual tackling with internals of structures.

@umair-mohammad suggested to override `view.check_object_permissions`, but again, that i wished to avoid, because it meant that all my views should be inherited from one base class. In most cases this is OK and thank you for your answer -- that indeed solves the problem -- but i really wanted to separate this logic into `permissions.py` without touching the views.

So, let's instead override the base permission class:

```
class AbstractPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_permission_by_global_role(self, request, view):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Project):
             project = obj
         elif isinstance(obj, Image):
             project = obj.project
         else:
             raise ValueError(obj)

         # if user has global role big enough -- permit
         if self.has_permission_by_global_role(request, view):
              return True

         # otherwise -- assess his 'local' role (as before)
         upr = UserProjectRole.objects.filter(user = request.user, project = project).first()
         if upr is None:
             return False
         if isinstance(obj, Project):
             return upr.role == User.ROLE_OWNER
         return upr.role >= User.ROLE_DEVELOPER
```

Then we inherit our AtLeastSomething classes, changing `has_permission` to `has_permission_by_global_role`:

```
class AtLeastOwner(AbstractPermission):
    def has_permission_by_global_role(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_staff or request.user.role >= User.ROLE_OWNER

...
```

Thus, in views.py, we only need to specify permission_classes based on a permitted global role -- in our case, that is AtLeastOwner for Project and AtLeastDeveloper for Images.

I believe this is the most pythonic approach to this. One can further make this cleaner by providing each model with something like `.allowed_roles()` method.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**  - Try overriding `check_object_permissions(request, obj)`

As per DRF documentations :

> Before running the main body of the view each permission in the list
>   is checked. If any permission check fails an
>   exceptions.PermissionDenied or exceptions.NotAuthenticated exception
>   will be raised, and the main body of the view will not run.

Which means all the permissions which we have mentioned in `permission_classes` **MUST** pass. If anyone of them also fails, then it'll not authenticate.

1. So for our custom need we can override `check_object_permissions(request, obj)` and write our custom authentication.